# Angular 15: Adding router causes endless redirect loop

Tags: angular

I've got a simple Angular v15 application, and I've developed many Angular applications, but never ran into this issue. Once I add a router configuration, either via `RouterModule.forRoot(...)` or the new `provideRouter()`, I get an endless redirect problem.

When I browse to http://localhost:4200, /# keeps being added to the URL. Within a couple of seconds the URL is:

`http://localhost:4200/#/#/#/#/#/#/#/#/#/#/#/#/#/#/#/#/...` and growing.

I have no idea how this happens. Just adding this line to my AppModule imports causes this problem: `RouterModule.forRoot([])`

Answer (score 0):

After removing literally everything, turned out it's because of the Office JS add-in scripts, as it's an Office Web Based addin.

Then, configuring the router to use the hash based strategy (useHash:true) fixed the issue.